# Custom module name is rejected by Python syntax

Tags: python, import, syntax

I can't import my custom module I set up, which has a dash in the name and is rejected by Python's syntax checking. It went through just fine when I uploaded it.

I've searched for alternatives for `-` but I can't find any.
That or I'm just not good at finding things on search engines.

My error message:

```
>>> import english-dictionary
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import english-dictionary
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This should work, but I can't find out why.
Can anyone help?

Comment: First try renaming your custom module with `english_dictionary` and comment if that works.

Comment: About that... there are no dashes anywhere.

Comment: what is the name of your module you have made ?

Comment: `english-dictionary` I don't know where the dash came from

Comment: what's your `.py` file of custom module `english-dictionary` named as ?

Comment: Apparently there was a dash in the `__init__.py` that I missed. It fixed it, I guess.